# Run VSCode debug in WebStorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm migrating from VSCode to WebStorm. I can't find or run the `launch.json` debug in WebStorm.

How can I configure WebStorm to run VSCode files?

Comment: *"How can I configure WebStorm to run VSCode files?"* You cannot. You will have to create appropriate Run/Debug Configurations in WebStorm from scratch. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-code.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration.html